# how to select only unique record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have used the following mysql query:

```
select q.question,q.formnumber,g.forename,a.guardiancode from tblfeedbackquestions q
join tblfeedbackanswers a on q.id=a.questionid join tblguardian g on g.guardiancode=a.guardiancode where q.formnumber='3'
```

Output of this query is:

[image]

Now what i want is only the first row for same guardiancode should appear like in output for row 1 and row 2 i have guardian code as 10025 but i want only the first row and similarly for each unique guardiancode.Please help me with this.

Comment: Which row is 'first' and why?

Comment: try unique a.guardiancode

Comment: i tried unique and distinct but it shows error

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unique a.guardiancode from tblfeedbackquestions q
join tblfeedbackanswers a on ' at line 1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try adding `GROUP BY`:

```
select q.question,q.formnumber,g.forename,a.guardiancode 
from tblfeedbackquestions q
join tblfeedbackanswers a on q.id=a.questionid join tblguardian g 
on g.guardiancode=a.guardiancode 
where q.formnumber='3'  
GROUP BY g.guardiancode
```

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions the use of a GROUP BY clause is always inappropriate.

Comment: ya i will...it will accept it after 10 minutes...but thanx buddy

Comment: While GROUP BY looks to work in MySQL, the correct way to eliminate duplicates from the result set is to use DISTINCT. GROUP BY should only be used with aggregate queries.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is appropriate for normal situation but for unique situation like this `GROUP BY` is more appropriate. For example if the OP did not include `q.question` then `DISTINCT` should be the right tool. But since he wants to include `q.question` then `GROUP BY` is the more appropriate tool. If efficiency or optimization is not in question here then this method should not be malign.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` to get unique values from tables,

```
  SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table_name;
```

Added `DISTINCT` for guardiancode column,

```
   select q.question,q.formnumber,g.forename,DISTINCT a.guardiancode from tblfeedbackquestions q join tblfeedbackanswers a on q.id=a.questionid join tblguardian g on g.guardiancode=a.guardiancode where q.formnumber='3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a group by. I'm not sure about MySQL, but in most SQL implementations, this means you can't display values that aren't  grouped. So for example:

```
select a.guardiancode, min(q.id) 
from tblfeedbackquestions q
join tblfeedbackanswers a on q.id=a.questionid
join tblguardian g on g.guardiancode=a.guardiancode
where q.formnumber='3'
group by a.guardiancode;
```

You can now join the result of this query with question on question id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
ie:

select q.question,q.formnumber,g.forename,a.guardiancode from tblfeedbackquestions q
join tblfeedbackanswers a on q.id=a.questionid join tblguardian g on g.guardiancode=a.guardiancode where q.formnumber='3' group by  a.guardiancode

hope it will works... :)